AWS4 Signature invalid, why this happens?
When trying to do a request with the generated signature, i get the following error:
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been...
The String-to-Sign should have been...

However, comparing to the results that i logged in the console, they're identical (the ones from my console to the ones which it expects)
I find this very odd when the data is the same, it must be something with my code that i am missing
My code is:
import crypto from "crypto";

export default class V4 {
  constructor(region, service) {
    this.region = region;
    this.service = service;
  }

  generateSignature(requestData) {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(requestData.requestUrl);

    const longDate = this.getDate();

    const requestHeaders = {
      host: parsedUrl.host,
      "x-amz-date": longDate,
      "x-amz-security-token": requestData.sessionToken,
    };

    console.log(requestData.requestUrl)

    requestData.requestPath = parsedUrl.pathname;
    requestData.requestParams = parsedUrl.searchParams;

    requestData.requestHeaders = requestHeaders;

    const canonicalRequest = this.buildCanonicalRequest(requestData);

    console.log("canonicalRequest: " + canonicalRequest);

    const shortDate = this.getFormattedDate(longDate);

    const stringToSign = this.buildStringToSign(
      canonicalRequest,
      shortDate,
      longDate,
      this.region,
      this.service
    );

    console.log("stringToSign: " + stringToSign);

    const signingKey = this.getSigningKey(
      requestData,
      shortDate,
      this.region,
      this.service
    );

    const signature = this.sha256Hmac(stringToSign, signingKey);

    const signatureData = {
      signature: signature,
      longDate: longDate,
      shortDate: shortDate,
    };

    return signatureData;
  }

  buildStringToSign(canonicalRequest, shortDate, longDate, region, service) {
    const credentialKey = `${shortDate}/${region}/${service}/aws4_request`;
    const canonicalRequestHash = this.sha256Hash(canonicalRequest);

    let stringToSign = [];

    stringToSign.push("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
    stringToSign.push(longDate);
    stringToSign.push(credentialKey);
    stringToSign.push(canonicalRequestHash);

    return stringToSign.join("\n");
  }

  buildCanonicalRequest(requestData) {
    const canonicalHeaders = this.buildCanonicalHeaders(requestData);
    const signedHeaders = this.getSignedHeaders(requestData);
    const payloadHash = this.sha256Hash(requestData.requestBody);

    let canonicalRequest = [];

    canonicalRequest.push(requestData.requestMethod);
    canonicalRequest.push(requestData.requestPath);
    canonicalRequest.push(requestData.requestParams); // none
    canonicalRequest.push(canonicalHeaders);
    canonicalRequest.push(signedHeaders);
    canonicalRequest.push(payloadHash);
    
    return canonicalRequest.join("\n") ;
  }

  buildCanonicalHeaders(requestData) {
    let canonicalHeaders = "";

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(requestData.requestHeaders)) {
      canonicalHeaders += `${key}:${value}\n`;
    }


    return canonicalHeaders;
  }

  getSignedHeaders(requestData) {
    const keys = Object.keys(requestData.requestHeaders);
    return keys.join(";");
  }

  getSigningKey(requestData, shortDate, region, service) {
    const dateKey = this.sha256Hmac(shortDate, "AWS4" + requestData.secretKey);
    const dateRegionKey = this.sha256Hmac(region, dateKey);
    const dateRegionServiceKey = this.sha256Hmac(service, dateRegionKey);
    const signingKey = this.sha256Hmac("aws4_request", dateRegionServiceKey);
    return signingKey;
  }

  getDate() {
    const date = new Date();
    return date.toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, "");
  }

  getFormattedDate(date) {
    return date.substr(0, 8);
  }

  sha256Hash(data) {
    return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(data).digest("hex");
  }

  sha256Hmac(data, secretKey) {
    return crypto.createHmac("sha256", secretKey).update(data).digest("hex");
  }
}

I tried debugging, the data looks the same, result is the same, invalid signature
